# Fazer uma DIV empurrar o resto do conteúdo para baixo

Tags: html5, css3

Tudo certo?
Tenho uma dúvida aqui, mas queria entender, não apenas pedir para as pessoas fazerem o que preciso. 
Vou tentar explicar: Eu tenho um botão de adicionar linhas de texto. Abaixo desse botão, tenho uma DIV com 600px de altura onde serão criadas essas linhas cada vez que forem adicionadas pelo botão.

Embaixo dessa DIV, há uma outra que só coloquei pra teste.
O que eu quero entender como fazer é: Eu preciso que assim que o número de linhas criadas dentro da DIV ultrapasse os 600px, a altura acompanhe a criação das linhas e empurre a outra div pra baixo. 
Isso é feito através de posicionamento, não é? Ou estou enganado e é preciso de mais coisas?

Muito obrigado pessoal! Como eu falei, é uma dúvida de conceito! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Olá. Se você não tiver feito nenhuma mudança de posicionamento, a div de baixo se posicionará automaticamente de acordo com a altura definida pela de cima.
O que acontece é que você, provavelmente, delimitou o tamanho exato da div de cima. Algo como:`height: 600px`. Em vez de usar essa propriedade, você deve usar a `min-height`. Assim, o elemento "por padrão" terá 600px de altura mas, se você adicionar mais conteúdo, ele vai automaticamente se adequar, empurrando a outra div para baixo.

```
.div-superior{
  min-height: 600px;
}
```

Comment: Lucas, muito obrigado cara!
Acertou em cheio no que eu precisava entender. Coloquei dessa forma e funcionou certinho!
Na verdade, o foco do meu estudo é javascript, mas surgiu isso e eu realmente não sabia ao certo o que fazer. Tentei mudar posicionamento em si, pesquisei e não encontrava. Muito obrigado mesmo! 
Grande abraço!

Comment: Abraço e de nada. Bons estudos :)